# Quando é que se pode usar Traje, usar terno e usar fato ao identificar uma roupa?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, português-europeu, uso-de-palavras

Quando é que se pode usar Traje, usar terno e usar fato ao identificar uma roupa?
Tenho ideia que no Brasil se usa Terno e em Portugal Fato para identificar a mesma coisa. Será assim?
Por exemplo o uso de traje académico?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, aquela vestimenta que chamamos de "terno" no Brasil, é chamada de "fato" em Portugal. Não posso afirmar se o portugueses também utilizam a palavra "terno" mas, deste lado do Atlântico, acho que 99,99% da população não saberia o que é "fato" ou um "guarda-fatos".

Já a palavra "traje" refere-se ao tipo de vestimenta.

> O substantivo masculino [**traje**](https://duvidas.dicio.com.br/traje-ou-trage/) é sinônimo de roupa e vestimenta, indicando aquilo que se veste habitualmente, bem como o vestuário próprio de um determinado evento ou de uma determinada profissão.

> traje social

> traje passeio

> traje passeio completo (para o homem, significa terno e gravata.)

> traje de gala

> traje esporte

> traje esporte fino

Existe também o [**verbo trajar**](https://duvidas.dicio.com.br/traje-ou-trage/)

> É importante que ela se traje de preto neste evento.

> Você quer que eu me traje de bruxa para a festa?

> O suspeito trajava uma calça jeans e camiseta.

Comment: Como por exemplo, traje academico